# Is it possible to make `allow_growth = True` set by default in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I know that for Tensorflow, if we have not set `allow_growth` to `True`, the GPU memory will be totally mapped to the program to avoid memory fragment by default. However, I am building a multi-user system which will support multi-user using the same card simultaneously. Naturally, I do not hope the GPU memory totally allocated, so it seems `allow_growth` setting to `True` by default will easily solve the problem.

But how can I make `allow_growth = True` by default outside Tensorflow?

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the environment variable `TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH` to the value `true`. Note that I found this in Tensorflow's code - it is not a documented feature.

Answer (score 1):

The `allow_growth` option is documented here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu

Currently, the way you configure `allow_growth` is via the Tensorflow session options in each Python script.

The idea of configuring it via an environment variable has been raised before:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8040

In general since Tensorflow is a library, we are trying to keep configuration via programmatic means, such as the Session options. However, if you want to turn this off by default in your models, you could write a helper library that sets things up as you like them.

As to why `allow_growth` is not the Tensorflow default; I'm not sure. I suspect it is to do with fragmentation issues. You could open a github issue requesting that it be made the default.

Hope that helps!